# use docker-composer in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, devops, cicd

Tell me please, is it possible to somehow run the script from the docker collaborator via gitlab-ci.yml

**My docker-composer.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: USER/test-web_app:latest
    ports:
      - "9876:80"
```

**My gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:

stages:
  - build_project
  - make_image
  - deploy_image

build_project:
  stage: build_project
  image: node:16.15.0-alpine
  services:
    - docker:20.10.14-dind
  script:
    - npm cache clean --force
    - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 15 mins
    paths:
      - build
      - node_modules
  only:
    - main

make_image:
  stage: make_image
  image: docker:20.10.14-dind
  services:
    - docker:20.10.14-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $REGISTER_USER -p $REGISTER_PASSWORD $REGISTER
  script:
    - docker build -t $REGISTER/$REGISTER_USER/$PROJECT_NAME:latest $DOCKER_FILE_LOCATION
    - docker push $REGISTER_USER/$PROJECT_NAME:latest
  after_script:
    - docker logout
  only:
    - main

deploy_image:
  stage: deploy_image
  image: alpine:latest
  services:
    - docker:20.10.14-dind
  before_script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$SERVER_IP \
      docker login -u $REGISTER_USER -p $REGISTER_PASSWORD $REGISTER
  script:
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$SERVER_IP \
      docker-compose down
   **?????????**
  after_script:
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$SERVER_IP docker logout
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$SERVER_IP exit
  only:
    - main
```

How can I use a docker-composer script inside gitlab-ci to run it on a remote server?

Is it possible to use several different docker-composer for different build versions?

Comment: What error messages or problems did you run into with what you tried already?

Comment: @sytech I didn't encounter any errors.  Before that, I uploaded the image to the server through docker run.  But this is inconvenient, since it is necessary to pass some variables that the programmer will include.  and it was decided to switch to docker-composer.  But since I have never done devops work, I have a question.